# PhpStorm: I have this wired problem in Blade template files, don't know how to describe it

Tags: phpstorm

I've been using PhpStorm for a while now and there is one thing that bothers me a lot.**Tab completion** inside a file that ends with `.blade.php`.

I write this line in a `.blade.php` file:

```
div.w-2/5.rounded.shadow
```

When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it effectively generates this markup:

```html
<div class="w-2/5 rounded shadow">

</div>
```

So far so good. But when I try to do the same inside the `div` some weird behavior happens,

[image]

I'm guessing that the PhpStorm's Blade compiler interprets the `h1` (or any other tag, I tried that) as a Blade element instead of a regular HTML element.

But when I do that outside any parent it works as expected.

[image]

The tab completion works and I get this output, which is expected:

[image]

Comment: Show screenshot of your `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections` -- whole list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me.
Looks as if you have some language injected in `<div>` tag... do you have any custom injections defined in **Settings | Editor | Language Injections**? Check all injections with *IDE* or *Project* scope

Comment: yes that worked, i accidentally must've added that, thanks a lot